# Tkinter: Adding a entry at index 3 without there being one at index 1 or 2

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, listbox

The problem im getting is if type something in my entry box it first fills index 1 and 2 of the listbox before finally typing into the 3rd index.

```
def country_get(event):
        listbox.delete(3)
        listbox.insert(3, country_label.cget('text') + event.widget.get() + '\n')




title_text=StringVar()
entry_country=Entry(master, bg="wheat3", fg="dark slate gray", textvariable=title_text)
entry_country.bind('<KeyRelease>', country_get)
entry_country.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

I want to be able to type at any index of the listbox whether it be the 3rd or 5th, without having anything at the previous index's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many entries I'm using or need, i just insert empty strings like so:

```
listbox.insert(0, "")
listbox.insert(1, "")
listbox.insert(2, "")
listbox.insert(3, "")
listbox.insert(4, "")
```

It appears that the listbox is empty when it fact it is just filled with empty strings. There are most likely other ways to get around this, but for what I need my program to do, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want. The listbox isn't designed to have empty rows. If you want empty rows, you will need to insert empty strings.

Comment: Is it possible to add a loop, where it checks to see if index 1 and 2 have been filled, if not to check back in a second and if it does then to continue? could threading and queues be of any help?

Comment: @KalibKumeroa: yes, it's possible. No, threading and queues would not be of any help.

Comment: could you please give me an idea of what loop would work. I've tried a couple loops (e.g. while listbox() is < 2:), but everything seems to freeze the main gui because the program is getting stuck in that loop and the mainloop() isn't continuing.